# Dealing with multiple user session types in DDD

Tags: design, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design, dependency-injection

I am developing an application which will use user sessions stored both in the client and on servers. Should I treat them as different repository implementations and use DI to use them inside domain services? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your context, the concept of "user sessions" sounds a lot like an *infrastructure concern* your domain layer shouldn't care about. So yes, as long as client vs. server user sessions isn't a *domain concept*, I would hide the technical origin of that data from the domain by injecting a service.

Whether that service is a *repository* (which is usually an abstraction for loading *domain objects*), I cannot say - that again depends on your domain. Are you loading aggregates/entities from the user sessions? If so, the service seems to be a repository. If not, it's probably not.